# Homotopy pullback preserving functor

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

In the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101162.pdf, the authors claim during the proof of Prop. 4.2 that a functor $F:A \to B$ which preserves fibrations and weak equivalences preserves homotopy cartesian squares. It seems to me that without asking it to commute with ordinary pullbacks the claim is false.

Moreover, it is also stated that the induced functor $A^C \to B^C$, where $C$ is a Reedy category, preserves Reedy fibration. Again, I think it has to commute with pullbacks (e.g. a right Quillen would satisfy everything of the above for fibrant objects).

Am I right or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Concerning the first claim, I don't see any problem, a square is a homotopy pull-back iff the induced map between homotopy fibers of parallel arrows is a weak equivalence.

Comment: I know, but still I can't see how to conclude without that commutativity assumption

Comment: @FernandoMuro, the proposition in the paper says that the functor preserves fibrations in the model structure, not fibre sequences.

Comment: @AdeelKhan if it preserves fibrations and weak equivalences, then it preserves homotopy fiber sequences.

Comment: @FernandoMuro, I may be missing something, but if $A$ and $B$ have the trivial model structures, then the condition of preserving fibrations and weak equivalences is vacuous, while the condition of preserving homotopy fibres is a type of left-exactness, right?

Comment: @FernandoMuro The last thing you said is false: take a constant function to a non terminal object

Comment: Denis thanks, now I understand Edoardo's and Adeel's concern. I agree with Edoardo that I wouldn't be able to prove the claim without asking that the functor preserves pull backs.

Comment: Ok, then I guess the authors should be informed of this issue

Comment: A correction to the paper has been added on Schwede's webpage: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/Correction-rss.pdf